# How to generate a user password in plain SQL with Django + PostgreSQL

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

I want to insert from a Django into another Django database from other domain a proper password text in auth_user table.

I have tried to generate a encrypt function but I don't know how Django generates a password from plain text into hashed password that is stored in database.

```
postgres_insert_query = """
          INSERT INTO auth_user (username, first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
        """
        record_to_insert = (username, first_name, last_name, email, password)
        cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query, record_to_insert)
        connection.commit()
        cursor.close()
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you do not use Django's ORM. It has builtin support for setting passwords.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, My Django application generates/edits/removes users from another Django application. It is not the case of more than one database in settings.py of the same application.

Comment: then it might be better to call the management command to create a user I think, for example with [`django-createuser`](https://pypi.org/project/django-createuser/).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem This tool is useful for shell scripts in a server to generate users, but my Django application is in one server, and the other Django application where I insert the users is placed in other server.

Comment: well the hashing algorithm is not fixed. You can change it by altering the `PASSWORD_HASHERS` setting: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords and therefore even if you manage to get it working, later it might fail, because the settings have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set_password` method of your `User` model will allow you to access both the raw password, and the hashed password. Here is an example:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    [...fields...]
    def set_password(self, raw_password):
        # Update the password in the current Django Project
        super().set_password(raw_password)

        # Insert the password into the other database
        cursor = connections["otherdb"].cursor()
        postgres_insert_query = """
          INSERT INTO auth_user
          (username, first_name, last_name, email, password)
          VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        """
        cursor.execute(
            postgres_insert_query,
            [self.username, self.first_name, self.last_name, self.email, self.password]
        )
        cursor.close()
```

In the example, we have access to the `raw_password`, and after called `set_password()`, we have access to the hashed password in `self.password`. This method will be called every time a user is created or modified within the ORM. For example, I've used this method for updating a hashed password in LDAP whenever it is changed in Django, by the end user or an administrator. Good luck!